# How to store values from a query result into a column with a nested foreach

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, foreach

Hi I am trying to store some values in a column using a query result with nested `foreach` something like this:

```
if ($migrate_centers) {
    $centersdt = $otf->getTable('centdt');
    $centersdt = $centersdt->get();
    $regions = $otf->getTable('ldt');
    //$regions = $regions->get();
    $regionsList = array();
    $result = array();

    try {
        $regions = $regions->select('ldt.lname')->leftJoin('centdt', 'ldt.lid', '=', 'centdt.centregion')->groupBy('centdt.centregion')->get();

        foreach($centersdt as $center) {

            $center4 = new Center;
            $center4->code = $center->centid;
            $center4->phone = $center->centphone;
            $center4->email = $center->centemail;
            $center4->region_id = $center->centregion;
            $center4->name = $Arabic->convert($center->centname);
            foreach($regions as $reg) {
                $center4->region = $Arabic->convert($reg->lname);
            }
            $center4->save();
        }




    } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

But I get only same value  in all rows

Comment: Can you post here (or if it's big somewhere else) result of `dd($centersdt);` placed before foreach loop.

Comment: it returns the table's content  , the problem is in the second foreach it stores the same value for all rows